# Why is this SOQL query not selective?

Tags: soql, timeout

We have following query in our code and its giving timeout error.

```
Select email, firstname, lastname, id 
From contact 
Where Email != Null 
And Opted_Out__c = false 
And id IN (Select contactid From CampaignMember Where campaignId = 'XXXXXXXXXXXX')
```

When we contacted SFDC support they said the query is not selective.

In SFDC [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=How-can-I-make-my-SOQL-query-selective-And-the-process-to-determine-the-fields-that-can-be-custom-indexed&language=en_US) its mentioned that :

> If the filter is on a standard field, it will have an index if it is a primary key (Id, Name, OwnerId), a foreign key (CreatedById, LastModifiedById, lookup, master-detail relationship), an audit field (CreatedDate, LastActivityDate, SystemModstamp).

In above example both inner and outer SOQL uses ID and so it should be selective query.

Can someone takeout time and explain me why its not Selective Query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think i found the reason why its not selective query.

When we use inner query SFDC cant use index. It doesnt matter whether we pass  NULL into IN clause. If we just pass the list of IDS then query becomes selective and it works fine.

Here is is screen shot of my test.[image]

[This](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Developing_Selective_Force.com_Queries_through_the_Query_Resource_Feedback_Parameter_Pilot#InefficientOperators) blog helped me to reach to this conclusion.

Answer (score 2):

If you were already in touch with SF support, it doesn't harm to ask them for more details, they have access to data & logs specific to your org. I believe the culprit is the following:

```
Where Email != Null
```

As far as I know the != operator can not rely on idexes and will always result in a full table scan.

The [documentation](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_SOQL_VLSQ.htm) states:

> Typically, a custom index won't be used in these cases:
>
> - The filter operator is a negative operator such as NOT EQUAL TO (or !=),NOT CONTAINS, and NOT STARTS WITH The CONTAINS operator is used in
>     the filter and the number of rows to be scanned exceeds 333,333. This
>     is because the CONTAINS operator requires a full scan of the index.
>     Note that this threshold is subject to change. When comparing with an
>     empty value (Name != '')

The [Query & Search Optimalization Cheat Sheet](http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/194/0/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_query_search_optimization_developer_cheatsheet.pdf) also lists `!=` as an exception.

Comment: Hi Samuel, Thank you very much for your reply on this. I don't think that Email != Null can make query non selective. As per documentation any query with at least one one selective term is called as selective query. Please refer example # 5

Comment: Same question is sent to SFDC support too so lets see who can solve this fast :)

Comment: Please refer example # 5 from this link https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=How-can-I-make-my-SOQL-query-selective-And-the-process-to-determine-the-fields-that-can-be-custom-indexed&language=en_US

Comment: In my understanding it's only selective when it returns below a certain % of your data, regardless of how many filters and indexes that requires. I don't see how #5 explains anything,  many presentations and webinars around this subject mention that  using the != operator is a bad idea for, as I believe, the reason as described above. But yes, maybe I misinterpreted that, i guess we'll see how the community evaluates my answer.

Comment: I certainly agree that != is bad idea but i doubt that its creating problem in this case. I think Null is root cause here.  I am running Explain and will share result with you. Thank you very much for your help on this! :)

Comment: Hi Samule, Can you please review my updated answer?

Comment: I'm not sure what I can do, it is your question. Does your answer solve your problem or not ? You may very well accept your own answer if it resolves your issue ! It is a good answers, you did your research and went into more detail than my answer which only pointed out one obvious aspect. Votes are up to the community, accepting an answer is up to you.

Comment: By Review, I mean did you see any point that I might have missed or miss interpreted.  Thank you once again for your comments. After checking the authenticity of answer i surly accept it.